# (React) Selecing different dropdown values does not change anything

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, state

I have a dropdown menu, and selecting different values does not change anything. Previously, it did change just fine. Here is my code:

**context.js**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import items from './data'

const RoomContext = React.createContext()

const RoomProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        rooms: [],
        sortedRooms: [],
        featuredRooms: [],
        loading: true,
        type: 'all',
        capacity: 1,
        price: 0,
        minPrice: 0,
        maxPrice: 0,
        minSize: 0,
        maxSize: 0,
        breakfast: false,
        pets: false
    })

    const formatData = items => {
        let tempItems = items.map(item => {
            let id = item.sys.id
            let images = item.fields.images.map(image => image.fields.file.url)
            let room = { ...item.fields, images, id }
            return room
        })
        return tempItems
    }

    const getRoom = slug => {
        let tempRooms = [...state.rooms]
        const room = tempRooms.find(room => room.slug === slug)
        return room
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let rooms = formatData(items)
        let featuredRoomsTemp = state.rooms.filter(room => room.featured)
        let maxPrice = Math.max(...state.rooms.map(item => item.price))
        let maxSize = Math.max(...state.rooms.map(item => item.size))

        setState({
            ...state,
            rooms,
            featuredRooms: featuredRoomsTemp,
            sortedRooms: rooms,
            loading: false,
            price: maxPrice,
            maxPrice,
            maxSize
        })
    }, [])

      const handleChange = e => {
        const target = e.target
        const value = e.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
        const name = e.target.name

        setState({
            ...state,
            [name]: value 
        })
        filterRooms()
    }

    const filterRooms = () => {
        console.log('reached')
        let { rooms, type, capacity, price, minSize, maxSize, breakfast, pets } = state

        let tempRooms = [...rooms]
        if (type !== 'all') {
            // console.log('NOT ALL')
            tempRooms = tempRooms.filter(room => room.type === type)
        }   
        console.log('temprooms:' ,tempRooms)

        //ONLY AFTER ADDING THE BELOW SETSTATE,  AM I UNABLE TO CHANGE THE DROPDOWN VALUES. IF I REMOVE THE BELOW, I CAN CHANGE IT JUST FINE. Why would a setState make me unable to change the values?
        setState({
            ...state,
            sortedRooms: tempRooms
        })
    }

    return (
        <RoomContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            getRoom,
            handleChange
        }}>
            {children}
        </RoomContext.Provider>
    )
}

const RoomConsumer = RoomContext.Consumer

export function withRoomConsumer(Component) {
    return function ConsumerWrapper(props) {
        return <RoomConsumer>
            {value => <Component {...props} context={value} />}
        </RoomConsumer>
    }
}

export { RoomProvider, RoomConsumer, RoomContext }
```

**RoomsFilter.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { RoomContext } from '../context'
import Title from './Title'

const getUnique = (items, value) => {
    return [...new Set(items.map(item => item[value]))]
}

const RoomsFilter = ({ rooms }) => {
    const context = useContext(RoomContext)

    const { handleChange, type, capacity, price, minPrice, maxPrice, minSize, maxSize, breakfast, pets } = context

    let types = getUnique(rooms, 'type')
    types = ['all', ...types]

    types = types.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <option value={item} key={i}>{item}</option>
        )
    })

    return (
        <section className='filter-container'>
            <Title title='Search rooms' />
            <form className='filter-form'>
                {/* select type */}
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <label htmlFor='type'>Room type</label>
                    <select name='type' id='type' value={type} className='form-control' onChange={handleChange}>
                        {types}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {/* end select type */}
            </form>
        </section>
    )
}

export default RoomsFilter
```

==================================================================

As you can see, it is only when I added

```
setState({
            ...state,
            sortedRooms: tempRooms
        })
```

in **filterRooms** **(in context.js)** that I am no longer able to change the dropdown value. Why would adding **setState** do this?

Please help, and thank you for reading!

===============***UPDATE***=====================

1. RoomsContainer is the one that contains the Dropdown menu(RoomsFilter) and the list of rooms below that dropdown menu(RoomsList).
2. RoomsFilter is the dropdown menu component
3. RoomsList is the component whose job is to render the rooms

Rooms Container:

```
import React from 'react'
import RoomsFilter from './RoomsFilter'
import RoomsList from './RoomsList'
import { withRoomConsumer } from '../context'
import Loading from './Loading'

function RoomContainer({ context }) {
const { loading, sortedRooms, rooms } = context
console.log(context)
if (loading) {
return <Loading />
}

return (
<div>
<RoomsFilter rooms={rooms} />
<RoomsList rooms={sortedRooms} />
</div>
)
}

export default withRoomConsumer(RoomContainer)
```

RoomsFilter:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { RoomContext } from '../context'
import Title from './Title'

const getUnique = (items, value) => {
return [...new Set(items.map(item => item[value]))]
}

const RoomsFilter = ({ rooms }) => {
const context = useContext(RoomContext)

const { handleChange, type, capacity, price, minPrice, maxPrice, minSize, maxSize, breakfast, pets } = context

let types = getUnique(rooms, 'type')
types = ['all', ...types]

types = types.map((item, i) => {
return (
<option value={item} key={i}>{item}</option>
)
})

return (
<section className='filter-container'>
<Title title='Search rooms' />
<form className='filter-form'>
{/* select type */}
<div className='form-group'>
<label htmlFor='type'>Room type</label>
<select name='type' id='type' value={type} className='form-control' onChange={handleChange}>
{types}
</select>
</div>
{/* end select type */}
</form>
</section>
)
}

export default RoomsFilter
```

RoomsList

```
import React from 'react'
import Room from './Room'

const RoomsList = ({ rooms }) => {
console.log(rooms)
if (rooms.length === 0) {
return (
<div className='empty-search'>
<h3>Unfortunately no rooms match your search criteria</h3>
</div>
)
}

return (
<section className='roomslist'>
<div className='roomslist-center'>
{rooms.map(item => {
return <Room key={item.id} room={item} />
})}
</div>
</section>
)
}

export default RoomsList
```

Comment: Your code seems very messy and overengineered. I recommend refactoring your code and using the latest state. this can be done by calling the functional arguments in your setState. setState(prev => ({...prev...)

Comment: @Continuum This is from a udemy course...not my own. I have asked the author but it is taking ages to get a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different `setState` calls; one is in your `handleChange` function, and the other is inside of `filterRooms`. Both of those functions on a given change are using the previous state, but after the first:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  [name]: value 
})
```

...`state` is still going to have that same original value when you call:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  sortedRooms: tempRooms
})
```

...so the second update is going to overwrite what the first `setState` did. As was already pointed out, you can use the callback version of setState for the second call so you're using the *new* previous state on that second call:

```
setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  sortedRooms: tempRooms
}));
```

...but a *better* approach is to only call `setState` *once* on change instead of confusingly making two state updates. Instead of `filterRooms` calling `setState`, have it *return* the filtered Array, and do your update all in one call. Here's what filterRooms could do instead:

```
const getFilteredRooms = (type) => {
  let { rooms, capacity, price, minSize, maxSize, breakfast, pets } = state
  return type === 'all' ? rooms : rooms.filter(room => room.type === type)
}
```

...and change your `handleChange` to:

```
const handleChange = e => {
  const target = e.target
  const value = e.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
  const name = e.target.name

  setState({
    ...state,
    [name]: value,
    sortedRooms: getFilteredRooms(value)
  })
}
```

Comment: Wow Jacob thank you so much, your explanation is very good and now I can change the dropdown menu. If I may ask one more though:

By default the value is "all". If I change to "family", it does nothing. However if I change to, say, "double" after "family", it shows "family" instead. So now I am in "double" but it is showing "family". If I then change again to "single", I will now show double.

Basically I am always behind 1 step. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: I have no idea! I don't see what could be causing that. When you say "it shows..." where is it that the wrong type is showing?

Comment: I am so close to the solution thanks to you, but this one little thing is preventing me from reaching the finish line! So, basically the issue is:

1. Dropdown menu by default shows "all".
2. I change it to "single", nothing happens. "ALL" rooms are still being showed/rendered.
3. I change again to "double", and only then do I see all the "single" rooms.
4. So right now I am seeing all the "single" rooms although the value of dropdown is "double" (as I said, 1 step behind).
5. If I change to "family", I will now see all the "double" rooms, even though the dropdown value says "family"

Comment: Right, I'm asking where are you seeing these "ALL rooms" or "single rooms?" Is that in code you haven't posted?

Comment: That would be in the actual localhost:3000 (the frontend, the UI), sorry if I misunderstood your question.

I would love to post the other codes that I think are relevant to fixing this issue, but writing in the comment is very limited :( Its because I feel there are 2 more codes to show you so that you can get the whole picture

Comment: You could edit your question with additional info, but it sounds like it might be easier to ask in a separate question since it sounds like it might be an unrelated issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215129/discussion-between-5ecured-and-jacob).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the setState correctly .. it should be used like this instead

> setState(prevState => ({...prevState , sortedRooms: tempRooms}))

Comment: Thanks @Rami GB. I did not realize that is how you do it using hooks. I always thought for example:
`const [height, setHeight] = useState(10)`
and to change, you simply have to `setHeight(15)`
I did not know there is a prevState props

Comment: I tried and I got an error. May I ask if you perhaps thought I was using class based component?

Comment: It's a common syntax bug; for arrow functions returning an object literal, you have to wrap it in `()` since it otherwise thinks the `{` is an opening brace for the function, not the object. Changing to `setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, sortedRooms: tempRooms }))` would work instead (or see my answer)

Comment: @5ecured it works this way when you are trying to access the previous state. other wise the usage you mentioned is correct if you are setting primitives not objects. as Jacob has mentioned you might need to wrap it with () just as in his example. I'll update my answer accordingly.